How do I decrypt an encrypted rsa 2048 encoded string?
I have a requirement to replace my non-encrypted RSA private key with an encrypted one.
I used
openssl ... -newkey rsa:2048 -new sha256 ... 

(Omitted non-essential stuff)
to generate the pem. I see that the generated pem begins with "----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----".
(It used to just say -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----")
When I try to use that pem file in the existing Java code, it throws an InvalidKeySpecException
 PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String path) throws Exception{
    String algorithm = "RSA";
    try{
        String rsaPrivateKey = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path)));
        Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path)));
// tried with and without the following replaceAll() 
        rsaPrivateKey = rsaPrivateKey.replaceAll("-----.*?-----", "");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder(rsaPrivateKey)).decode(rsaPrivateKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactor.getInstance(algorithm);
// next line throws the exception 
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        return privKey;
    }catch(InvalidKeySpecException e){
// this is getting thrown 
    }
}

I tried adding new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(rsaPrivateKey.getBytes()) to decrypt it before the decode() call, but that threw its own exception.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk: no, that ctor is for creating (i.e. writing) a encrypted PKCS8, not reading one

Preliminarily there are lots of errors in your Q.

There is no command openssl -newKey rsa:2048 -new sha256 .... You mean openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -sha256 ... (req must be present, -newkey must be lowercase, digest must begin with -).

rsaPrivateKey.replaceAll("-----.*?-----") doesn't compile. If you add the required second argument as "" it compiles but does entirely the wrong thing and mangles your data.

Base64.getDecoder(rsaPrivateKey) doesn't compile (assuming java.util.Base64) and if it did wouldn't be the correct argument for new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec which could instead by the result of calling .decode(body) on data from an unencrypted key file.


The correct way to de-PEM your type of file is
String body = string_without_linebreaks.repaceAll ("-----(BEGIN|END) ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----","");
// or if you have some fetish about generality
// = string_without_linebreaks.replaceAll ("-----(BEGIN|END)[A-Z ]*-----","");
// followed by 
Base64.getDecoder().decode(body)

but you can't use this directly as a PKCS8EncodedKeySpec because that must be unencrypted.
javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo is indeed the plain-Java way to read encrypted PKCS8 -- but for PKCS8 using PBES2 (as OpenSSL now does) it only works if the cipher is AES-128 or AES-256, while openssl req creates a file encrypted with PBES2 and triple-DES (aka TDEA, DES3, 3DES, DESede). IF you re-encrypt your file with e.g.
openssl pkey -in from_req.key -aes-128-cbc -out fixed.key

then for that file after the de-PEM above you can parse the result with
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo epki = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo( base64_decoded );

and in Java 19 up you can decrypt it with simply
SecretKey kek = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( epki.getAlgName() )
    .generateSecret( new PBEKeySpec (your_password_as_chararray) );
PrivateKey pkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePrivate (epki.getKeySpec(kek));

but below 19 you must either use the hack I showed here or hardcode e.g. PBEwithHmacSHA256andAES_128 for the SKF -- or SHA1 if you use(d) OpenSSL below 1.1.0, now more than 8 years old and rare.
Alternatively in all versions of Java and for all (normally used) PKCS8 encryptions you can read the PEM directly using BouncyCastle, as I referenced there, and many other Qs have addressed.

Sorry I abbreviated some of the commands. The replace does not mangle the key, it works perfectly, not sure what you mean

@VictorGrazi: The replace does not get rid of the -----BEGIN and -----END lines.

Sorry,  my office blocks stack overflow, so I had to type everything over manually, sorry for the errors and abbreviations. For the non-encrypted version, I had to do the replaceAll as above, to get rid of the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----. With the encrypted version I tried it both ways, but no luck

You could also use the Java key tool command to do all this
This is the JDKs native way of managing cryptographic keys and certificates.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
